# Trying to find the title of a SF Short story about a pregnant astronaut in the 80's

Tags: story-identification, books

This short story is from a collection I read in the early 80's about a pregnant astronaut with an alien life form that would change humans. I vaguely remember something about fuzzy eyes.

Comment: Can you remember any more details? This is pretty vague.

Comment: It's only vague if you haven't read the story.  The fuzzy eyes is a dead giveaway if you've read "Green Patches."

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84574/short-story-about-astronauts-landing-on-a-planet-of-shapeshifters (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 10):

I think it's Isaac Asimov's classic short story, ["Green Patches"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Patches), found in ["Nightfall and Other Stories".](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/70771.Nightfall_and_Other_Stories)

> “That is correct. Saybrook said so and we corroborate him. After the
>   rats, the pet cat of one of the children was obviously affected. When
>   it finally kittened, the kittens were not born with closed eyes but
>   with little patches of green fur. There was no tomcat aboard.
>
> “Eventually Saybrook had the women tested. He didn’t tell them what
>   for. He didn’t want to frighten them. Every single one of them was in
>   the early stages of pregnancy, leaving out of consideration those few
>   who had been pregnant at the time of embarkation. Saybrook never
>   waited for any child to be born, of course. He knew they would have no
>   eyes, only shining patches of green fur.

Comment: Since when did Asimov write anything that creepy? Hopefully Halle Berry's new series ends with the baby being born with green fur instead of eyes.

Comment: That is super creepy...

Comment: @James Sheridan: That would be too awesome for Hollywood.